# One to many association. Undefined method

Tags: associations, undefined, one-to-many

I have a table countries and a model Country with the following columns id,cc_fips,cc_iso,tld, country_name with all the countries in the world listed.

I have a table users and model User with columns id, name, age...........

Every user has one country but one country has many users.

I want to create a table in the middle where i will register columns country_id, user_id.

A one to many association.

I named the table countryforusers and the model Countryforuser.

My migration to create the model:

```
class CreateCountryforusers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :countryforusers, {:id => false} do |t|
      t.integer "country_id"
      t.string "user_id", :null => false, :default => ""
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index("countryforusers","country_id")
  end
end
```

My model User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  belongs_to :countryforuser
end
```

My model Countryforuser:

```
class Countryforuser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

However it doesn't work.
I have all the time a message undefined method `countryforusers' when trying to add one user for a country.

What am i doing wring?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Although each user has one country and one country many users, i had to use a many to many association, if i would put a join table in the middle. So the word many to many is a bit confusing this time.